# must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Tags: function, jsp, el

I tried to run EL function on Tomcat v7 server but it failed.

JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" name="" id="Rcept_<%=i%>" value="${QStr.str_hl( incidentTpEtt.rceptCtts)}">
```

Error:

> The function str2html must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

So I tried the following code

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %> 
<input type="hidden" name="" id="Rcept_<%=i%>" value="${fn:str_hl(QStr, incidentTpEtt.rceptCtts)}">
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="" id="Rcept_<%=i%>" value="${fn:QStr(str_hl, incidentTpEtt.rceptCtts)}">
```

Error:

> The function str_hl cannot be located with the specified prefix

`QStr`:

```
public static String str_hl(String as_str) {
    char[] l_str = null;                                                    
    int li_len = 0;                                                          
    StringBuffer l_return = new StringBuffer();                               

    if(as_str == null)                                                       
        return null;

    l_str = as_str.trim().toCharArray();
    li_len = l_str.length;

    for(int i=0 ; i<li_len ; i++) {
        if     (l_str[i] == '&')  l_return.append("&amp;");
        else if(l_str[i] == '<')  l_return.append("&lt;");
        else if(l_str[i] == '>')  l_return.append("&gt;");
        else if(l_str[i] == '"')  l_return.append("&quot;");
        else if(l_str[i] == '\'') l_return.append("&#39;");
        else l_return.append(l_str[i]);
    }
    return l_return.toString();
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have understood the problem.You have defined the method as static So calling it With class name is perfectly fine just one thing you missed is you should `use scriplet` there.

`<input type="hidden" name="" id="Rcept_<%=i%>" value='<%=QStr.str_hl( incidentTpEtt.rceptCtts)%>'>`

To be able to use the EL you must define the instance in one of the scope like Session, Request or Page then only you can use it.

Note:- you should also define the instance `incidentTpEtt` before calling the `str_hl` method.

Comment: I changing code

    <input type="hidden" name="" id="Rcept_<%=i%>" value='<%=QStr.str_hl( incidentTpEtt.rceptCtts)%>'>

-> ${QStr.str_hl( incidentTpEtt.rceptCtts)}

Comment: Why negative vote ? Are you expecting full solution just by looking at few lines of code ???   I have given him an example that with these lines he can't use `EL` but he should use `scriplet`.